# compiling error when i add facebook sdk in my iPhone project

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

i download facebook sdk from this link https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ in this some sample projects are present from which hackbook full fill my needs but when i add files in my project and after calling this line compile error comes

`Facebook *ff = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"my_app_ID" andDelegate:self]`;

compiler says some thing like this "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from"

please help me i just want to post status on facebook any help please ....

Answer (score 3):

This error is not related to Facebook SDK. I think you are using sqlite wrapper in your program and you are not linking it correctly.

If you are using sqlite wrapper then, make sure you're linking to the SQLite library! In the left pane of your project window in Xcode, expand Targets, click on your target, and command-i to get info. Under the "General" tab you will see "Linked Libraries". Verify that libsqlite3.0.dylib is in the list here, and if not, click the "plus" icon and add it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Follow the directions in step 5 here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/#project

Basically hidden in all those steps and text is some important info that you have to follow to add the framework correctly.

Comment: I had to add `-lsqlite3.0` in the Build Settings. See section #5 on the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

xcode/Build Settings 
Other Linking Flags -lsqlite3.0

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Facebook error. This is actually related to the wrapper, and there is an error in linking the two.

By the way, I work in a small group from the development sector for Facebook. We're looking for opinions on some of our new features, including Timeline, due to odd feedback already received. Why not take a minute and let us know what you think? It seems as though your opinion would be useful to us. We look forward to hearing from you! Check it out here:  http://tinyurl.com/8qj95sa